# revmob banner gets red and flicks in iphone5

Tags: iphone, banner, revmob

I added revmob ads banner at the bottom of my app.
But it shows red box only, and sometimes it flicks.

What's the matter?

I used to add the fullscreen ads, so I don't know about the revmob banner ads.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution! :)

I'm afraid there are few references about the revmob ads for iOS(especially for iphone5).

I wrote my code [Revmovads showbannerAdWithDelegate:nil] on 
viewWillAppear function.

It was just issue.

I moved it to viewDidAppear, and now the ads view is clear!

Thanks :)